# iOS TabBar Icons Design with Tips and Implementation: How To?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tabbar

my designer wants to have Tab Bar Icons similar to the ones in the fitbit app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fitbit/id462638897?mt=8

How is it done with those tips looking up?

Does the designer have to design it like this?

Or is it done in code?

Thanks a lot for your insights!

Comment: This might help you - http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bctabbarcontroller

Huge source: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar

Comment: Guys, you are invaluable! Thank you! So, basically, the designer creates the image, I put it onto a button and the button goes onto a tab of a tab bar. Cool :)

Comment: Precisely. Glad to help. If it helped, please mark as correct (press check sign), which will help you get quicker answers in future too!

Comment: You are confused in your question. Your question is about design. Please post different question or search the site. People are here to help you only if you follow certain rules. No one does any free work. You will only get help if you do your research, ask correct questions, mark answers as correct and return the favor in terms of votes etc. whenever applicable.